# Suppressing axis titles in a graph scheme

Tags: graph, formatting, stata

I have written a few schemes which, after a lot of digging, include almost all of the formatting I would like. The one exception is suppressing the axes titles.

Currently I use the entries below to accomplish this:

```
color axis_title bg
gsize axis_title zero
```

Although this works, it causes confusing behaviour for the user when they specify options such as `ytitle()`, `xtitle()`, because the title is not produced. What is produced is a tiny title box, which is only noticeable when exporting to certain formats.

I have looked through the standard schemes but I have not found anything that helps.

For example, I tried the following:

```
yesno axis_title no
```

In summary, I would like to specify something in the scheme that suppresses axis titles by default but will allow the user to use an axis title if they specify `ytitle()` and `xtitle()` in the normal way:

```
twoway ... , ytitle("My Title")
```

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished, or if there is a scheme that already does this?

This question has been [cross-posted](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1353019-suppressing-axis-titles-in-a-scheme) on Statalist.

Comment: If someone knows the solution to this, I am willing to award a bounty additionally to up-voting the correct answer.